# How to show docx and pdf files?

Tags: android, pdf, docx

What do I want to achieve? I want to choose pdf or doc file and show them on recyclerview. What have I done?

Firstly, I tried to start activity like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimetypes = {"application/pdf", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open document"), DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When this attached document is clicked, I do following:

```
Intent docIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/doc_name"));
        docIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(docIntent);
```

Above method opens Google Docs to load document and it can open only docs located on Google Drive. There is black view when I try to open document located in device storage. URI of document located in device is : `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/doc_name` and URI of document located in Google Drive is like : `content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D430`

After some searching I changed click method to following:

```
        File file = new File("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/doc_name"); // url here is string type


        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); //only pdf here
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "No Application Available to View PDF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

But in above method, `exists()` returns false. Note, that all `url` that I pass are string type. So, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: `document.getUrl()`. It is pretty unclear what `document` would be. Start at the start please.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. I just have document class that returns url etc. Basically, it is simple URL in string type.

Comment: That is not enough info of course. If url is a String then please tell its value/content. Put it in your post like `String url = "......"; `

Comment: Why are you starting two intents in one on click handler?

Comment: @greenapps Fixed and edited. Can you check and help?

Comment: No. Not yet fixed. I asked you to add String url = .... to your code. Please do.

Comment: @greenapps Unfortunately, I edited the question as I've understood from your comment

Comment: You edited it again so we can continue. What you want is impossible. You cannot use the `File` class for a content scheme. So forget the second intent. Your first intent should work for pdfs. Did you install pdf viewer apps? And a docx viewer app?

Comment: @greenapps Of course. I have viewers. I think the problem with uri

Comment: `When this attached document is clicked, I do following:`. Well you do wrong. You should use setDataAndType() there.